# What happens to the rest of the light that didn't get filtered by polarized film?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, polarization

Suppose I used a polarized film to produce say left circularly polarized light, I wonder what happens to the rest of the light that gets absorbed or reflected away? Are those unpolarized or right circularly polarized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical circular polarizer consists of two layers: a linear polarizer with, say, a vertical orientation; and a birefringent layer whose axis is tilted at 45 degrees.  The linear polarizer absorbs the horizontally polarized components of incident light and transmits the vertically polarized components; then the birefringent layer converts the vertically polarized transmitted light to circularly polarized light. The final polarization state is right-circularly polarized or left-circularly polarized depending on whether the 45 degree tilt is clockwise or counterclockwise.

If a reflective linear polarizer is used instead of an absorptive linear polarizer, then in the example above the reflected light is horizontally *linearly* polarized, and the vertically polarized light the polarizer transmits is converted to circularly polarized light by the subsequent birefringent layer.